# how to call a static method inside a class in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a static method inside my class. How can i use or call this method inside my class

```py
class myClass:
    @staticmethod
    def myFunc(self):
        print(something)

    def anotherFunc(self):
        #how can i call myFunc here
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling from an instance method, you can do as follows.

```
In [1]: class Dog: 
   ...:     @staticmethod 
   ...:     def bark(): 
   ...:         print('bork') 
   ...:     def greet(self): 
   ...:        self.bark() 
   ...:                                                                         

In [2]: d = Dog()                                                               

In [3]: d.greet()                                                               
bork
```

While your example is correct Python, the `myFunc` shouldn't take a `self` parameter because it is a class method not an instance method. This is misleading to someone looking at your code.

Otherwise, you can access it from the class level.

```
In [4]: Dog.bark()                                                              
bork
```

In the future, I would highly suggest using the Python Read Evaluate Print Loop (REPL) to run small snippets like this.